# Redirect any queries on non-existent files to one php file

Tags: .htaccess

I need to redirect any queries on non-existent files to one php file.
Im trying to make works nexmo inbound SMS.

I don't have any experience in .htaccess, that why I ask the community..

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

Please note that you re expected to find a solution yourself by at least *trying* to solve your task yourself. There are many examples for what you ask in answers here on SO and there also is an *excellent* documentation of apache's rewriting module two clicks away. So "I don't have any experience" is not a good reason to not try yourself but simply ask us for a solution. Please consider that.

Anyway, here *is* the solution you ask for:

```
RewriteEngine on
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^ /path/to/file.php [END]
```

In case you receive an internal server error (http status 500) using the rule above then chances are that you operate a very old version of the apache http server. You will see a definite hint to an unsupported `[END]` flag in your http servers error log file in that case. You can either try to upgrade or use the older `[L]` flag, it probably will work the same in this situation, though that depends a bit on your setup.

This rule will work likewise in the http servers host configuration or inside a dynamic configuration file (".htaccess" file). Obviously the rewriting module needs to be loaded inside the http server and enabled in the http host. In case you use a dynamic configuration file you need to take care that it's interpretation is enabled at all in the host configuration and that it is located in the host's `DOCUMENT_ROOT` folder.

And a general remark: you should always prefer to place such rules in the http servers host configuration instead of using dynamic configuration files (".htaccess"). Those dynamic configuration files add complexity, are often a cause of unexpected behavior, hard to debug and they really slow down the http server. They are only provided as a last option for situations where you do not have access to the real http servers host configuration (read: really cheap service providers) or for applications insisting on writing their own rules (which is an obvious security nightmare).